# Failed to read row 0 , Column -1 From a cursor window in Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Failed to read row 0 , Column -1 From a cursor window in Sqlite database

I used this code .

```
public Misc fetchmiscdetails(Context aContext,
            String acityName, String aLangName) {
        Misc miscobj = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String where;
        try {

            String sqlTables = "misc";  
            where ="Select * from misc ";
            cursor = db.rawQuery(where, null);
        //  if (aLangName.equals("English"))
        //       where = "city_name = ?";
        //  else
        //       where = "city_name_ger = ?";

            qb.setTables(sqlTables);

        //  cursor = qb.query(db, null, where, new String[] { acityName}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    miscobj = new Misc(
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_id")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("countyr_id")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_name")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_name_ger")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_lat")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_long")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_population")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_timezone")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_gmt")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_dst")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_lat_long")), 
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_category")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_text")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_rowoffset")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_value"))

                            );
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return miscobj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return miscobj;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you try to get value from the `Cursor` for a column which either does not exist or was not included in the `Select` query.

Since you are selecting all the columns it is most likely that you made a spelling mistake in one of the column names.

Most likely

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("countyr_id"))
```

Compare all the column names in the method to the names that you use in your `Create` statement for `misc` table.

Comment: Its Working.. Thanks , there is problem with two enteries 
1.cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_rowoffset"))to cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_rawoffset")),